# How do I retrieve the object I passed in jQuery.ajax()'s `data` attribute on the server side (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

I made a chrome extension which calls jQuery's `ajax` method:

**content-script.js**

```
[...]
$.ajax({
    "url": "http://localhost:5000/",
    "type": "PUT",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "data": { "name": "random object" },
    "dataType": "json"
});
[...]
```

On the server side, I'm trying to fetch the information passed in the `data` attribute:

**web.js**

```
[...]
app.put('/', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.data);
});
[...]
```

But I'm getting `undefined` instead. How is the object passed in the `data` attribute supposed to be retrieved on the server side ([Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [express.js](http://expressjs.com/))?

I also tried `console.log(request)` and got a LOT of stuff in there, but nothing that looked like the info I passed along in the `data` attribute...

**EDIT**

My latest attempt (based on graydsl's answer) brings the following changes to the code above:

- Added `app.use(express.bodyParser());` just before `app.put...`.
- Changed `put` to `post` everywhere
- Changed `request.data` to `request.body.data`

Now, the code does what I want when responding to a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input name="data" type="text" value="WOO HA" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

However it still fails if I revert to using `post` instead of `put` (and the browser ends up on `http://localhost:5000/?data=WOO+HA&submit=submit` for some reason)

It also fails when `put`ting (or `post`ing) with ajax (see code above). When I try it with ajax, I get this on the server:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/shawn/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/1.8.7/package/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:135:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:61:17)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1019:22)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:683:27)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As others have mentioned, and you're now doing, you need to use the bodyParser` middleware.
2. If the request body has a content type of "application/json", `bodyParser` will parse it into an object, which will be located at `request.body`. Thus in your case `request.body.name` should be "random object".

I think you (and several of the previous responders) are mentally hanging up on the fact that jQuery's `ajax` method uses the key name "data" for an object to be sent (serialized as JSON) in the request body, and magically sliding to the assumption that anything on the server side that processes the request will also call that object by the name of "data". There's no connection between the two.

Comment: I managed to make the code in my original post (before the edit) work with the following changes: As you suggested, use `request.body.name` rather than `request.data` & using `JSON.stringify` on the object passed to jQuery's data attribute. Here is the working example: content-script: http://pastebin.com/iY1V5bWC , on the server: http://pastebin.com/r7B6sjdm . However, this does not work cross-domain. Instead, my browser (chrome) blocks the PUT and says "Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." This is another question though.

Comment: FYI I tried using GET instead of PUT with the same result: It gets blocked by chrome when cross-domain.

Comment: @Shawn as far as the cross-domain stuff is concerned, have you tried sending the right headers back from inside your epxress route?

    res.header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
    res.header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With"

Comment: Fantastic.  I had this same issue (req.body was undefined every time).  I did not realize I need to add the `app.use(express.bodyParser())` line to my server configuration.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `req.body.data`. Something like this should work:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.data);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Take a look at this link: [bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html)

I hope I could help you! :)

**EDIT:** Just found a nice lib for working with $.ajax, it's called: [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). You might consider giving it a try. Looks promising. :)

## Update

The problem lies in your jquery code not in the node.js code. You can't send an object in the `data` property of the `settings` object, you have to *stringify* the data object first. You can use the `json2.js` from the awesome *D - to the - ouglas Crockford*: [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

After you included that library the following code should give you the result you want:

```
$().ready(function() {

    var data = {
        data: "My name is",
        name: "Slim Shady"
    };

    stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
        "type": "PUT",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "data": stringifiedData,
        "dataType": "json"
    });
});
```

And in the app.js:

```
app.put('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.data + "... " + req.body.name);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: This does not work: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Do you use the bodyParser middleware? Something like `app.use(express.bodyParser());`?

Comment: Maybe change res.redirect to res.send or something. Because res.redirect doesn't really do what you expect it to do when the request is using ajax.

Comment: I'm still getting undefined... Could you post a working example? I'm sure I've just got a small detail wrong. Here is one of my failed attempts: http://pastebin.com/BqBTR8rY

Comment: Note that you have to use `app.post(...)`, because the bodyParser ignores GET requests. ;) [Here](https://gist.github.com/2699689) is a working example.

Comment: You are sending a `PUT` from jQuery and but in express you are using `post('/'`. Typo?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery data attribute gets translated into a query string or post data before being sent to server. To retrieve it, use node.js to decode GET and POST parameters.

You said you use express.js.  In express.js, if you pass `data` like this: `{ EmployeeName : "George" }` then, in express.js, `request.params.EmployeeName` will contain "George".

Comment: I tried using POST instead of PUT, but still `request.params.key` returns `undefined` (`request.params` returns `[]`).

Comment: Try making a request by hand in the browser to www.test.com/my-handler?test_var=test_string and then check request.params. If it returns passed strings, then may be the code that passes the data is incorrect.

Comment: I tried using GET instead of POST and using the browser's url bar to make the request with `http://localhost:5000/myHandler?randomName=randomObject`. Still, `request.params.randomName` returns `undefined` and `request.params` returns `[]`.